# Memory management issues in Unity3d

Tags: memory-management, unity-game-engine, texture2d

Im calling Texture2D function on void OnGUI().And Im adding 5 prefabs in 5 seconds and those are destroying in 20 seconds. This all prefabs using Texture2D. I'm not destroying Texture after use. When I run this game, it use lot of memory and it is increasing. Shoud I need to destroy this generated Texture?

```
public static Texture2D Colors(int r,int g, int b)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; ++x)
            {

                Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
                texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();

        return texture;
    }
```

**Edit**

Ok. This is what I actualy try to do. I have a class Called HealthSystem 
[On Github](https://github.com/sjnilan/HealthBarSystem)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthSystem : MonoBehaviour {
float healthBarLenght=20f;//Length for Healthbar;

public static void Set_HealthBar(Transform transform,int HealthBarHeight,   float CurrentHealth,float MaxHealth,Texture2D BackBar, Texture2D FrontBar)
        {
        Vector3 screenPosition;

        GUIStyle style1 = new GUIStyle();
        GUIStyle style2 = new GUIStyle();
        float HPDrop = (CurrentHealth / MaxHealth) * healthBarLenght;

        screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        screenPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPosition.y;

        style1.normal.background = BackBar;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(screenPosition.x-(healthBarLenght/2),screenPosition.y-20, healthBarLenght,HealthBarHeight),"",style1);

        style2.normal.background = FrontBar;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(screenPosition.x-(healthBarLenght/2),screenPosition.y-20, HPDrop,HealthBarHeight),"",style2);
}


    public static Texture2D Colors(int r,int g, int b)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; ++x)
            {               
                Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
                texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }
}
```

Im calling this from another script

```
void Start () {
        colorback = HealthSystem.Colors (0, 0, 0);
        colorfront = HealthSystem.Colors (0, 255, 0);
    }

void OnGUI(){

            HealthSystem.Set_HealthBar (transform, 2f, 70f, 100f, colorback, colorfront);

    }
```

This script attached to my eminy troops. 5 enemies are spowning by 5 second. And they will be destroyed in 20 seconds. This enemy object are using Physics.OverlapSphere to identify their enemies

Comment: "Should I need to delete?" Yes, try that indeed.

Comment: Im new to Unity. So how to destroy Texture in this function.

Comment: Hmm, let me just think this. Why are you using for loops if you know that Texture2D texture is always 2x 2y ? Could you also show the onGUI() code? :)

Comment: Texture2D BackBar=Colors(0,255,0);
style1.normal.background = BackBar;
/*Just now I added this code to here*/
Destroy (BackBar);

Comment: Where is the spawning?

Answer (score 1):

OnGUI is called one time per frame. so dont instantiate or create any thing in OnGUI. Unlikely what you think, it doesnt create just one texture. Every frame it creates one new texture. Creating and deleting also will be a bad code. you need to create this texture in void Start()

Comment: Yes it should work. Thanks. Ill try and let you know

Comment: It didn't help much. I still having the problem :(

Comment: can you share code of function where you call Colors function?